# What makes this more general trend model "better"?

Tags: forecasting, model, trend

In class, my professor defined a trend model as $X_{t} = m_{t} + Y_{t}$ where $m_{t}$ is "slowly varying", which we do not yet have a formal definition for. He then immediately just redefined it as 
$$X_{t} = \alpha_{t} + \beta_{t}t + Y_{t}$$
where $\alpha_{t}$ and $\beta_{t}$ are "slowly varying", and said we'd usually use this because it's better, without elaborating.

I can understand that in the latter case we have a slowly varying term attached to a $t$, but I can't conceptualize why this exactly would make a trend model any *better*. What is it about this more general form that gives it an advantage over the former?

Comment: You seem to be asking us to speculate about your professor's thinking. You should ask him why he thinks it's better -- there might be any number of reasons depending on what aspects one considers.

Comment: @Glen_b I'd agree with you, except we got a review question for our midterm asking why the latter is better than the former. Which wasn't explained in class... leaving it to myself, I really am not sure.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I would say that the more general form looks like a simple regression model. So we would be assuming less about the dependence structure of $Y_{t}$?